# Using Double Quote in String

Tags: c#, xml, string, concatenation

This is a silly question and maybe it is messing me up because it is late in the day, but why is the following code below also putting in the back slashes when I try to use a double quote:

C#:

```
private List<string> dataList;
        private int ShowAuditLogForPrimaryID { get; set; }
        private string xmlString;
        private DataSet _dataSet;

  SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            dataList = new List<String>();


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    string rdr = reader[i].ToString();

                    dataList.Add(rdr);

                    string Name = reader.GetName(i); 

                    xmlString = xmlString + Name + "=" + " " + "\"" + dataList[i].ToString() + "\"" +  " ";

                    Console.WriteLine(xmlString);
                }
```

It is including the backslashes in the string which is not allowing my xml reader to be able to read it.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it's adding in the backslashes, try printing out the string as the debugger will show you backslashes in the string.

Comment: What is a sample output?

Comment: It doesn't, you are making some mistake. Are you looking at the value in the watch window (in which case it is the VS debugger that does the insertion)

Comment: Are you sure its actually in the string? The debugger often shows the escaped string.

Comment: Can you post your actual code?  What you have wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Well You all are right and I look silly haha. I actually never realized that what was in the debugger was different than the actual output... Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks fine, aside from the fact that you are using a variable before it is written.  Try printing out the string to the console if you want to see what's in it; if you look at it in the debugger, the debugger will try to escape the quotes again.

More generally, try to avoid writing code like this. Some ways you can make your code more clear are:

First, use constants judiciously:

```
const string quote = "\""; 
const string space = " ";
const string equals = "=";
xmlString =  Name + equals + space + quote + dataList[i].ToString() + quote + space;
```

That's now much easier to read because you haven't got all those quotes in there.

Second, the call to `ToString` is unnecessary. The string concatenation logic will automatically call `ToString` if necessary.

Third, use `String.Format` judiciously.

```
const string xmlAttributeFormat = "{0} = \"{1}\" ";
string xmlString = String.Format(xmlAttributeFormat, Name, dataList[i]);
```

Comment: This is great @EricLippert! You always have good answers! Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: The text visualizer can display strings without escaping them.  Single-click on the string in one of the watch windows and hit enter to view the string in the text visualizer.  Turn off wrapping if necessary.